# One Page website hashbang navigation scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

I planning to do   SEO optimisation for my One Page Website. 
I have one difficult thing to do, which is scrolling feature working with hashbang.  When i click on url from navigation, there is smooth scroll to section on that page.

```
<ul class="navigation" id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#personal-profile">Personal Details</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#work-experience">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#education">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this function i use for smooth scrolling:

```
function handleSmoothScrolling() {

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            console.log(target.offset());
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
          }
        }
    });
}
```

Everything fine when i  use default urls, but when im changing

```
<a href="#work-experience">Experience</a> to <a href="#!work-experience">Experience</a>
```

And the id of the section  div to id="!work-experience"  , the website is not scrolling,  and web browser trying to  load a non existing url.

Comment: should !# be #! in the href?

Comment: Hi.   Should be  #!andSectionNameHere

Comment: I asked because your example has !#

Answer (score 0):

You should use .htaccess or your servers equivalent to take care of the location change of #! to #, or better yet, assuming by the !# that you're using AngularJS, enable HTML5mode.